# Liquibase with column type numeric(x, y) is creating postgreSQL table with column type number

Tags: spring, postgresql, liquibase

I have a spring application connected to a postgreSQL DB. My issue is that this bit of script:

```
<column name="utmx" type="numeric(20, 5)">
    <constraints nullable="true"/>
</column>
<column name="utmy" type="numeric(20, 5)">
    <constraints nullable="true"/>
</column>
```

Is being executed like this:

```
CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.table (... utmx NUMBER(20, 5), utmy NUMBER(20, 5)...
```

As you can see, the column type NUMERIC is being changed to NUMBER on table creation.

Why is that? How can I solve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems Liquibase is thinking you are connected to an Oracle database. Using your column definitions against a Postgres database, Liquibase (3.10 and 4.6) generates: `CREATE TABLE public.some_table (utmx numeric(20, 5), utmy numeric(20, 5));` for me.

Comment: That's weird... For now I changed the type to decimal and it works, but I would like to know why it didn't work